# Advanced element selection using nth-child()

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a little problem with the `nth-child` selection. I need to get the next serie of number for apply a style:

3,4,7,8,11,12,15,16,....

[image: the idea is set the white background of the elements]

My solution is using two css rules:

```
.info div:nth-of-type(4n+4),
.info div:nth-of-type(4n-1)
```

But i want to know if it is possible using just one single selector.

Comment: Simple answer: no you will need 2 seperate selectors for this, like the selectors you're already using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use

```
div:not(:nth-child(4n+1)):not(:nth-child(4n+2))
```

but in my opinion the original version is more readable.